# How to get Cargo Test to Pretty Print Failure Outputs

Tags: testing, rust, format, rust-cargo, pretty-print

I have a Rust test that is comparing two structs of a type that implements `PartialEq` and `Debug`.

According to the help page for the `cargo test` output, it should be possible to "pretty print" the left and right arguments to each failed assertion:

```
$ cargo test_foo --lib -- --help

warning: `google2005` (lib test) generated 4 warnings
    Finished test [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.07s
     Running unittests (target/debug/deps/foo)
Usage: test_foo [OPTIONS] [FILTERS...]

Options:
        --include-ignored 
                        Run ignored and not ignored tests
        --ignored       Run only ignored tests
...
***** snipped *****
...
        --format pretty|terse|json|junit
                        Configure formatting of output:
                        pretty = Print verbose output;
                        terse = Display one character per test;
                        json = Output a json document;
                        junit = Output a JUnit document

...
***** snipped *****
```

I would expect this would print my structs with proper indentation, like when you use the `{:#?}` pretty print marker for `Debug` output. But it doesn't seem to have any effect:

```
$ cargo test test_foo --lib -- --format pretty
   Finished test [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.07s
     Running unittests (target/debug/deps/foo)

running 1 test
test parser::test::test_walk_scrapes_description ... FAILED

failures:

---- parser::test::test_walk_scrapes_description stdout ----
thread 'parser::test::test_walk_scrapes_description' panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)`
  left: `Cat { name: "Fluffy", age: 8, breed: "Siamese", color: "Brown", weight: 12, chip_number: 10001001 }`,
 right: `Cat { name: "Fluffy", age: 8, breed: "Siamese", color: "Brown", weight: 13, chip_number: 10010001 }`', src/parser.rs:170:9
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace


failures:
    parser::test::test_walk_scrapes_description

test result: FAILED. 0 passed; 1 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 13 filtered out; finished in 0.00s
```

I thought it was possible to do achieve something like this:

```
  left: `Cat {
             name: "Fluffy",
             age: 8,
             breed: "Siamese",
             color: "Brown",
             weight: 12,
             chip_number: 10001001
 }`,
 right: `Cat {
             name: "Fluffy",
             age: 8,
             breed: "Siamese",
             color: "Brown",
             weight: 13,
             chip_number: 10010001
 }`',
```

I've tried both with `rustc 1.59.0 (9d1b2106e 2022-02-23)` and `rustc 1.63.0-nightly (a6b8c6954 2022-06-03)`.

Comment: Not really an answer to handling this manually, but if you're okay with an extra dependency this library seems to do what you ask and more: https://github.com/colin-kiegel/rust-pretty-assertions

Answer (score 4):

This is quite problematic since [`assert_eq!()` itself prints the contents](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.65.0/src/core/panicking.rs.html#220-227) and `cargo test` gets already-formatted string.

It is also impossible to feature-gate the macro and under `test` pretty-print the variables, because `std`'s code cannot be feature-gated (currently).

You can however write your macro to do that, or use a library like [`pretty-assertions`](https://docs.rs/pretty-assertions).

Note, however, that there were RFCs to improve the display of the `assert!()` macros (it is not generally considered a breaking change), so it is possible that this will also be fixed in the future:

- [More readable assert_eq proposal](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1866)
- [Tracking issue for RFC 2011: nicer assert messages](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44838)